# Javascript in Servlet Response conflict with sendRedirect()?

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have some code like this written to add a alert box before the webpage is  redirected:

```
...
...
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
out.println("alert('testing');"); 
out.println("</script>");
...
...
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp")
```

unfortunately only sendRedirect() is success, the javascript added in the response is not working, is the sendRedirect() blocked the javascript? or something done wrong?

Comment: When you are using response.sendRedirect(), the javascirpt code won't get executed as page never loads before redirecting.


Why do you need alert statement?

Comment: Other way is to make an Ajax call and get the url in the response and from  through Javascript redirect to the same url.

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because out.println will be execute after compile jsp but as you are using the sendRedirect the previews code will not be compiled.

Can you try :

`out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
out.println("alert('testing');"); 
out.println("window.location="http://exemple.com/index.jsp";")
out.println("</script>");`

I think it work